# Program which checks the output of another program

Tags: c, linux, windows, ipc, pipe

I'm organizing a programming competition. I need to create a program which checks the output of another program (the participant's executable) character-by-character. The requirements are:

- The program must be `platform independent`.
- The input and the correct output for it must not be available to the participant. All a participant does is passes his program's name to the checker. The checker tells if the answer is correct or not, that's it.
- The output of the participant's program must not be shown to the participant himself - or he may figure out the input based on that.

For the second part, is it possible to store the input and the output within the executable itself somehow? I'd rather not read from an encrypted file.. it makes things a little inconvenient..

The program should work like this:

> checker.exe question1.exe
>
> Correct answer, congratulations!
>
> Please show this to a volunteer.

I tried using `popen` and `pclose` functions from the standard C library.

But the problem is that in Linux, it opens up a shell which shows the output of the participant's program, which shouldn't happen as per the 3rd requirement.

What could be a simple way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

I need to hand over the executables made for each question specifically to the participants.

Comment: Showing your code would help.  I don't think you need to do this in C -- a simple shell script worked fine when I needed to make such a script.  I don't have it anymore (that was over 15 years ago).

Comment: write it in code, store it in a database, store it on a webserver and make a request using sockets. Any of those should work although the simplest is to store it in the code.

Comment: A really clever competitor would write a program that clears the screen and produces the output shown above verbatim... how could you tell?

Comment: Is the program going to be run by the participant himself/herself ? Then there is no way one could control the participant from printing the input as-is :) You should instead let the user upload his program to your server, which would run the program and validate and return the result - if the program is correct or not.

Comment: @Hogan I need to hand over executables to participants.

Comment: @Tuxdude How? If the input and output are stored in the executable, how? I can safely assume no one will hack the executable.

Comment: @Bruce - see my answer, this is how I did it when I was a TA -- the program checked to see what grade they got.  They could run it themselves and know what grade they would get.

Comment: I really don't understand why I get a downvote for this.

Comment: @Bruce - re, downvote. Because people are dorks.

Comment: The code used by the ACM programming contests is available, why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is easy to never store the information in shell... just use pipe.

Eg

```
  $ question | checker
```

Checker can print if it worked or not.  It all happens in memory.

---

If you want the user to be able to do it themselves just put this code in a script file, set the file so the user has only execute and read priv. and then set the script to run as su.  Then the script can do the checking (that is run checker - or do a comparison).  If a comparison is needed the data file can be external to the script and the user does not have rights to that file then they can't read the data.

Comment: I think this is a viable option. The checker simply stores the hash of the correct output, reads the output of `question` from its standard input(right?), and just computes its hash and compares. Right?

Comment: You cannot execute a script without read permissions no matter if suid bit is set or not, as simple as that.

Comment: Sure, when I did it I did not bother with a hash, I just had another file of the correct out and did a `comp`.  Since I had the permissions set up right no one could read them without running the script

Comment: What I said above - piping the output of `question` to the checker, and verifying its hash - does it have any pitfalls? If not, it seems like the perfect solution to me.

Comment: @Bruce - it is fine - but slightly more complicated than needed IMHO

Comment: @Hogan Umm..can you please explain why is it complicated? I think its not since the participant just needs to add `| checker` to his executable name, and that's it.. the implementation is pretty straightforward too

Comment: @Bruce - Because I don't see the need for a hash.  You can have the data to compare external in a file that `checker` has rights to but the user does not -- then you don't need to do a hash.  A hash will work too.

Comment: @Hogan The user will always have rights to a file in his own laptop right! Anyway, I prefer hash, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @Hogan One more thing : piping will work exactly the same in Windows and Linux right?

Comment: @Bruce - yes but you have to be OS independent in how you look at the results-- for example care must be taken with CR/LF.  If there are CR/LF I suggest filtering before the hash.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to ask the users to encrypt the output of their program by a public key given by you : gnupg could be a good candidate. Decrypt the output using your private key and compare.

Otherwise it is not clear how one can compare without storing the output of a program to some file (binary or text) and without compromising the privacy of data.

Comment: You can hash the output of the program and compare it to a hash of the correct output. No need for decryption!

Comment: @Floris Yeah, I don't know why I didn't think about hashing!